# Does ng-required work with button submit ? Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I need to have ng-required in input forms , but it don't work with submit button which i also need to have. What can I do to have submit button works with ng-required, or any way to have the same effect ?

http://plnkr.co/edit/slITsvNWIttDHfxOpnmW?p=preview

```
<form name="myForm" validate class="form-horizontal">

  <div class="control-group" >
    <label ng-class="{bad: ( myForm.name.$invalid && submitted )  }"  >Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="user.name" ng-required/>
    <span ng-show="isInvalid('name')" class="help-inline">Name is ng-required</span>
    <span ng-show="isValid('name')">Great!</span>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" ng-click="submitted = true">SUB</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the value for `ng-required`. Set is to `true` and it should work.

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="user.name" ng-required="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that ng-required works only combined with required, so the input should look like this :

```
<input 
type="text" 
name="name" 
placeholder="Name" 
ng-model="user.name" 
ng-required="a == b"
required
/>
```